# Expanding : $(x+y)^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried solving $(x+y)^4$. So I figured:

1. I can solve it by $(x+y)^2(x+y)^2$, or
2. Using binomial theorem, or
3. I can also solve it by $[(x+y)^2]^2$; and this is where I get completely wrong answer!

Here's what I did, just so you can correct me:

$$ (x+y)^4 = [(x+y)^2]^2 = (x^2 + 2xy+y^2)^2=x^4+4x^2y^2+y^4$$

I know the last step doesn't make any sense. But this is what I did earlier. Now I'm confused how to solve it.

Comment: $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ac)$

Comment: The binomial theorem is the way to go.

Comment: But I would like to know how to go by [(x+y)2]2.

Comment: You write correctly that $$(a+b)^2\neq a^2+b^2$$ but then you write incorrectly that $$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2.$$

Comment: What does it mean to "solve" $(x+y)^{4}$? There is not an equation here to solve.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. I meant expanding.

Comment: Perhaps you are confuse because $x^2+2xy+y^2$ is no longer a binomial, but a trinomial ... See *Äres*' answer below who splits it into nested binomials

Answer (score 7):

Let's go back to basics. You need to understand that the formula $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ is just a shortcut for the calculation where you multiply $x+y$ by $x+y$ *by multiplying the terms "each by each"*:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}(x+y)^2&=&(x+y)\cdot(x+y)\\&=&x\cdot x+x\cdot y+y\cdot x+y\cdot y\\&=&x^2+xy+yx+y^2\\&=&x^2+2xy+y^2\end{array}$$

All the similar formulas must come from the same algebraic rules. In your case, if you want to square $x^2+2xy+y^2$, there are *three* terms, so after squaring you must end up with *nine* terms ($3\cdot 3$), which you can then tidy up:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}(x^2+2xy+y^2)^2&=&(x^2+2xy+y^2)\cdot (x^2+2xy+y^2)\\&=&x^2\cdot x^2+x^2\cdot 2xy+x^2\cdot y^2+2xy\cdot x^2+2xy\cdot 2xy+2xy\cdot y^2+y^2\cdot x^2+y^2\cdot 2xy+y^2\cdot y^2\\&=&x^4+2x^3y+x^2y^2+2x^3y+4x^2y^2+2xy^3+x^2y^2+2xy^3+y^4\\&=&x^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4 \end{array}$$

To simplify this particular calculation (raising a sum to a power), we have the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), but it is important for you to understand that, for every particular exponent, you can also go the "pedestrian" way as outlined here, and get the same result - as long as you don't forget to multiply the terms "each by each" when you are multiplying sums.

Comment: The first five to six lines of the Pascal's triangle could be a good mnemonic as well (for cross-checking), when in high-school.

Answer (score 2):

We have $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2.$

Now let $x=a+b$ and $y=c$ so $$(a+b+c)^2=(a+b)^2+2(a+b)c+c^2$$
$$=a^2+2ab+b^2+2ac+2bc+c^2$$
$$=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc).$$

Comment: That should work as well, @Äres , well done !

Answer (score 2):

The binomial theorem is the way to go.

Consider $$(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)$$

If we multiply that out we get sums of products of four terms. Can you see why this is so? When we expand the multiplication each of the $x$s and $y$s get multiplied by the $x$s and $y$s in the other parentheses. Therefore, we end up with terms like $xxxx$, $xyxy$, etc. Since multiplication is commutative, terms like $xxyy$ and $xyxy$ can be gathered together as $x^2y^2$.

Therefore, our final answer will have $x^4$, $x^3y$, $x^2y^2$, $xy^3$ and $y^4$ terms. To compute the coefficients of these we consider how many ways there are to get each one.

For $x^4$, there is only one way to do that. We take an $x$ from each of the parentheses. Likewise, there is only one way to get a $y^4$ term.

For $x^3y$, there are four ways because we only have one $y$ and there are four places we can get it from. Likewise, there are four ways to get an $xy^3$ term.

Finally, we consider the $x^2y^2$ term. How many ways are there to get two out of four choices? There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways. This is because we can get the first $x$ from four different places and for each of those there are three places from which to get the second $x$. That gives us $12$ but we have counted each set of choices twice so we must divide by $2$ to get $6$. For example, choosing an $x$ from the first set of parentheses and then choosing an $x$ from the second set of parentheses is the same as choosing an $x$ from the second set of parentheses and choosing the second $x$ from the first set of parentheses.

Therefore, we get that $$(x+y)^4 =x^4+4x^3y +6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4$$

Answer (score 0):

Use Pascal's triangle. Here's how it looks like :

[image]

This triangle can extend to infinity, but I have posted an example image of it (of how it looks like). You can use that to decide the coefficients of the terms in the expansion of $(x + y)^n$.

Here's a technique :

> NB : It will be good if you have a Pascal's triangle at hand, to make things simple; else you'll have to think hard about how to get the coefficients.

1. If you know what $x^n$ is, begin there.
2. Multiply $x^n$ by $\frac{y}{x}$ and write the result to the right side (after a sucfficient gap).
3. Repeat Step (2) till you get $y^n$ in the right end. Let's call that row we get by doing this process the 'row of variables'.
4. Using Pascal's triangle, taking the numbers in the $n^{th}$  row of the triangle, multiply each of the numbers in the row (from left to right) to the corresponding term in the 'row of variables' we made (from left to right) and write them down, with a plus sign in between each term.

I think that this yields less error in expanding $(x + y)^n$. Using this , the expansion you get for $(x=y)^4$ is : $$(x + y)^n = x^4 + 4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4$$

This is the same result you get when you do it algebraically as well.